# How do I get a reference to a rootViewController to a sub-view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, viewcontroller

An answer posted for one of my previous questions brings up another question; I am calling a new view  controller, "RuleBuilder," from my rootViewController. The  rootViewController holds a reference to a contacts array. How do I  get a reference to that array into the RuleBuilder? I tried adding

```
UITableViewController *rootViewController;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableViewController *rootViewController;
```

to  RuleBuilder.h, and then

```
@synthesize rootViewController;
```

in  RuleBuilder.m. When I instantiate and push the RuleBuilder from within  rootViewController, I do this:

```
ruleBuilder.rootViewController = self;
```

But  when I try this

```
[rootViewController.contacts addObject:newContact];
```

from  within RuleBuilder, I get a compiler error to the effect of "request  for 'contacts' in something not a struct" (or very similar; I haven't  implemented this exact snippet of code, but I tried an identical  approach not an hour ago for a couple of different references that I  never was able to get working).

Thanks, again, for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared the rootViewController property as a UITableViewController (which does not have a "contacts" property).

Most likely, your root view controller is a subclass of UITableViewController.  If you called that subclass RootViewController, then the rootViewController property in RuleBuilder should be declared as

```
RootViewController *rootViewController
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks for making the catch.